# Firebase firestore permission denied in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Android Kotlin project where I'm trying to retrieve a list of all documents from a collection (in the root) called 'environments' in firebase firestore. This is all new to me, but I can't get it to work. Research online didn't give me the correct answers on my situation so far.

#### Firestore structure:

```
ROOT
- environments (is a collection)
  - fMzUHbiK7QMsyEdnLmmfksu0j5L2 (is a document)
    - name: "number1" (is a field)
  - rgeEwg7RhWgWaqlmhwg46dWSfowl (another document, etc.)
    - name: "number2"
- users
- etc.
```

#### Security rules:

*(I'm sure the 2nd part (unsafe) would be enough, but I just tried explicitly)*

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /environments/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I've used the Firebase assistent to link my application to firebase. Also tried the manual method. So I've got this:

#### root-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### `app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies{
  // ..
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have the `google-services.json` file in the same directory as the root-level `build.gradle` as mentioned in the documentation.

I created a Kotlin project with 1 button (just to control when the functions fire, this function triggering will be automated later). *Note that I do not authenticate any users, I'm trying to create a happy flow for everyone, authentication and security come later.*

#### Kotlin

Now the following code is mostly from the official documentation

```
lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  // ...
  db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

  button.setOnClickListener {
  db.collection("environments")
   .get()
     .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
       for (document in result) {
         Log.d("success", document.id + " => " + document.data)
       }
     }
     .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
         Log.d("fail", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
       }
     }
   }
}
```

#### Debug/log

```
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreClient]: Initializing. user=null
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Start MutationQueue
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Allocate query
W/eldingenish_cw: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WatchStream]: (e57e2f1) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.ListenRequest@d97c49a6
    add_target {
      query {
        parent: "projects/[projectname-hidden]/databases/(default)/documents"
        structured_query {
          from {
            collection_id: "environments"
          }
          order_by {
            direction: ASCENDING
            direction_value: 1
            field {
              field_path: "__name__"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      target_id: 2
    }
    database: "projects/[projectname-hidden]/databases/(default)"

I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Successfully fetched token.
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WatchStream]: (e57e2f1) Stream is ready
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WatchStream]: (e57e2f1) Stream received headers: {date=Wed, 27 Feb 2019 12:34:34 GMT}
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WatchStream]: (e57e2f1) Stream received: # com.google.firestore.v1.ListenResponse@72b77077
    target_change {
      target_change_type: ADD
      target_change_type_value: 1
      target_ids: 2
    }
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [WatchStream]: (e57e2f1) Stream received: # com.google.firestore.v1.ListenResponse@d3efdcbe
    target_change {
      cause {
        code: 7
        message: "Missing or insufficient permissions."
      }
      target_change_type: REMOVE
      target_change_type_value: 2
      target_ids: 2
    }
I/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Release query
W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(environments) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

D/fail: Error getting documents:
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

#### Experiment

I started to believe my code was faulty, so I experimented some..

**Alternative**

```
.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
  if(firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
    Log.d("main", "Error ggetting documents")
    return@addSnapshotListener
  }

  querySnapshot?.documents?.forEach {document ->
    Log.d("main", document.id + " => " + document.data)
  }
}
```

**Adding document**

```
val item = HashMap<String, Any>()
item["name"] = "test"
db.collection("environments")
  .add(item)
    .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
      Log.d("main", "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + 
      documentReference.id)
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
      Log.w("main", "Error adding document", e)
    }
```

Nothing seems to have permission, while my security rules are good imo? (I can't test get collection in simulator, it only works with document paths) I can see that the application is linked to the project in the console. Also the usage of firestore reads is counting.

Can anyone help me?

*Note that I'm behind a Zscaler firewall. I've imported the certificate into Android Studio. My emulator has internet access but all SSL certificates are evaluated as invalid. I've also tried to run the app on my actual phone with 4G internet connection (no Zscaler).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted google service accounts (in the cloud platform) when creating the project. Was trying to begin from scratch, turns out the SDK uses these service accounts.

**Solution:** do not delete automatically generated service accounts!

Be aware, adding these service accounts manually is possible, but you can't select the roles they get when creating a project, you have to make them owner or pick specific permissions by trial and error to find out what they need.

*Another alternative way to query*

```
.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in task.result!!) {
            Log.d("1", document.id + " => " + document.data)
        }
    } else {
        Log.w("1", "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
    }
}
```

The code from the original post works too now! (and is neater imo)